# LinqToSQL Can't Update Twice

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext, insert-update

I try to update twice with same data but it throw exception

```
    public void UpdateOnSubmit<T>(T data) where T : class
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            using (DataModel dx = new DataModel(this._adapter.ConnectionString))
            {
                dx.GetTable<T>().Attach(data);
                dx.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, data);
                dx.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

the exception is

```
An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported.
```

First update is success but not in second. Thanks in advance

Regards,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay seem like i've found the solution again. I Just set DeferredLoadingEnabled to false and it work like a charm.

```
    public void UpdateOnSubmit<T>(T data) where T : class
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            using (DataModel dx = new DataModel(this._adapter.ConnectionString))
            {
                dx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
                dx.GetTable<T>().Attach(data);
                dx.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, data);
                dx.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```